# Notepad++ insert a 0 before second last character

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a list like this:

```
2044
2045
2046
103
106
109
```

On any line that is 3 digits long only I want to insert a "0" before the second last digit.

2044, 2045, 2046 are left alone and 103 changes to 1003, 1006, 1009.

In Notepad++ Regex I have Find: ^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$ which seems to highlight all the three digit lines, but I am stuck on inserting the 0 before the second last on these lines.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5):

You need to make use of Regex "*capture groups*" (any match between `()`), and "*backreferences*" to get the captured text back (`\1` and `\2` below).

Have a play on a site like regex101.com, which will also explain the Regex for you:

- Try: https://regex101.com/r/r09o0Q/3
- Find: `^([0-9])([0-9]{2})$`
- Replace: `\10\2`

After:

```
2044
2045
2046
1003
1006
1009
```

Comment: Oh nice! That worked great. Thank you. I will use this a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go without groups (more efficient):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=^\d)(?=\d\d$)`
- Replace with: `0`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=        # positive lookbehind, zerolength assertion that makes sure we have before current position:
    ^       # beginning of line
    \d      # 1 digit
)           # end lookbehind
(?=         # positive lookahead,zerolength assertion that makes sure we have after current position:
    \d\d    # 2 digits
    $       # end of line
)           # end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
2044
2045
2046
1003
1006
1009
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]